# Cometd server broadcast channels removing automatically

Tags: java, jetty, comet, long-polling, cometd

When I start the jetty, after sometime, broadcast channels are removing from the cometd automatically from the server. After that clients not receiving data. I have to restart the server time to time to avoid this. Please advise.

```
org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl.15947055  - Removed channel <channel_name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the [relevant section](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#java_server_configuration_channels) in the [CometD documentation](http://docs.cometd.org).